# Автоматически задавать расположение UIView на экране

Tags: ios, swift, uiview

Задача - получив массив содержащий в себе картинку и подпись к ней вывести на экран эти данные: две картинки, под ними еще две и т.д. (во вложении скриншот реализации).

В целом - я написал рабочий код, но он мне не нравится - я размещаю каждую картинку и подпись в UIView и задаю UIView место отображения на экране. Это нормально работает, если у меня всего 4 элемента в массиве, но если я захочу обработать 100 элементов - прописывать руками заранее расположение каждого UIView задача довольно глупая.

На CSS я бы расположил контейнеры в ряд с float: right и после каждого второго просто делал бы перенос строки...) Но как реализовать это на Swift?

```
let catalogList = ["1.jpg": "Стена", "2.jpg": "Микрофон", "3.jpg": "Инструменты", "4.jpg": "Концерт"]

var currentItems = 0

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    for i in catalogList {
        currentItems += 1
        if currentItems <= 2 {
            if currentItems % 2 < 1 {
                addNew(pic: i.key, text: i.value, x: 30, y: 65)
                } else {
                addNew(pic: i.key, text: i.value, x: 220, y: 65)
        }
            } else {
            if currentItems % 2 < 1 {
                addNew(pic: i.key, text: i.value, x: 30, y: 300)
                } else {
                addNew(pic: i.key, text: i.value, x: 220, y: 300)
            }
        }
    }
}

func addNew(pic: String, text: String, x: Int, y: Int) {

    let viewThing = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: x, y: y, width: 165, height: 220))
    self.view.addSubview(viewThing)
    let labelThing = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 5, y: 190, width: 165, height: 30))
    labelThing.text = text
    viewThing.addSubview(labelThing)
    let imageThing = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 165, height: 190))
    imageThing.image = UIImage(named: pic)
    viewThing.addSubview(imageThing)

}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте `UICollectionView` с необходимым `FlowLayout`. По скриншоту, условно, для каждой ячейки задавайте ширину в 1/2 ширины коллекции минус отступы между ячейками и высоту в 3/2 ширины ячейки:

```
let itemsPerRow: CGFloat = 2
let sectionInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 50.0, left: 20.0, bottom: 50.0, right: 20.0)
...
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView,
                    layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout,
                    sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    let paddingSpace = sectionInsets.left * (itemsPerRow + 1) 
    let availableWidth = collectionView.bounds.width - paddingSpace
    let widthPerItem = availableWidth / itemsPerRow
    let heightPerItem = widthPerItem * 3 / 2
    return CGSize(width: widthPerItem, height: heightPerItem)
}
```

[Ссылка на документацию](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionview)

[Очень детальный и развернутый пример на raywenderlich.com](https://www.raywenderlich.com/9334-uicollectionview-tutorial-getting-started)